# Get the second last record in a date column within a inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to pull the second last record in a date column called `OrderDate`. However, I need to bring only one date (I am making the search into a table with all the purchases orders, dates and costs, in which a have to bring only the second last and its cost). The way its query is written today (and working) is pulling me the the newest date.

```
select distinct 
    a.PurchaseNum, a.ItemID, a.SupplierNum, a.Location, a.OrderDate, a.Cost
from 
    PurchaseOrder a
inner join 
    (select 
         l.SupplierNum, l.ItemID, l.Location, maxdate = max(l.OrderDate)
     from  
         PurchaseOrder l
     where 
         l.Cost <> 0 
     group by 
         l.SupplierNum, l.itemid, l.Location) l on a.SupplierNum = l.SupplierNumand a.itemid = l.itemid 
                                                and l.Location = a.Location 
                                                and a.OrderDate = l.maxdate
```

I have tried to use `lag()`, offset (but with limitations once is within a join, forcing me to use the order by and include the `dateOrder` column which is not what I want because we need only one date)

A bit of context: I have a report in which I need to show the last and second last cost of a purchase order for each supplier. Bring the last cost of an order is easy, the problem is go back to the second last... and it is where I am stuck right now.

Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, here's one option using `row_number` to return the 2 highest `orderdate` records:

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
          row_number() over (partition by SupplierNum, ItemID, Location 
                             order by OrderDate desc) rn 
    from PurchaseOrder 
    where cost <> 0 
) t
where rn <= 2
```

Comment: . .. The question is a little hard to follow, but I think the OP want `rn = 2`.

Comment: it saved my week! I'm new to the SQL world and couldn't figure it out by myself without your help! Thank you!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wasn't 100% sure but assumed he wanted both from `I need to show the last and second last cost `. Sounds like it worked out for him though, thanks for the comment.

Comment: It worked properly, and with your code I have the ability to pull the second last only or both records. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Inner query does order by desc and outside query does order by asc.

```
select distinct top 1 a.*
from PurchaseOrder a
inner join 
(
select Top 2 l.*
 from  PurchaseOrder l
 where 
 l.Cost <> 0 
group by l.SupplierNum, l.itemid, l.Location order by orderdate desc) l
on  a.SupplierNum= l.SupplierNumand a.itemid = l.itemid and l.Location=a.Location and a.OrderDate = l.Orderdate
order by a.orderdate
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrder a
EXCEPT SELECT TOP (SELECT (COUNT(*)-2) FROM PurchaseOrder a where 
 l.Cost <> 0 
group by l.SupplierNum, l.itemid, l.Location) * FROM PurchaseOrder) A
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM PurchaseOrder a
WHERE OrderDate = ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
               FROM PurchaseOrder
               WHERE Orderdate < ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
                              FROM PurchaseOrder l where 
l.Cost <> 0 
group by l.SupplierNum, l.itemid, l.Location
                            )
             ) ;
```

or

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM PurchaseOrder
WHERE OrderDate < ( SELECT MAX(OrderDate) 
               FROM PurchaseOrder where ....
             ) 
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC ;
```